tails-os is not flashing into a usb
I am trying to create bootable live tails usb. I downloaded tails-amd64-6.10.img from here.
I verified the download:

I used balena etcher and got this error:


Since it did not work, I also downloaded from torrent but still same error.
I used different usb but still same error.

I tried using ventoy. ventoy does not see the image file. I put kali linux iso file into the ventoy and ventoy recognized it when I booted.

img file is not the same as iso file.
img is direct data to write to pendrive. Try to use Gnome Disk Utility as said in the instruction. It should write img file to the pendrive, and use whole drive, for example sdb, not partition like sdb1.
iso is a CD/DVD image which works a little different than img.
If this tool won't work you have always option to put the img file directly to pendrive by similar to this command:
sudo pv tails-amd64-6.10.img > /dev/sdb

or use program dd:
sudo dd if=./tails-amd64-6.10.img of=/dev/sdb status=progress

You will get progress with them both.
